# How to change the block title in siman cms

Tags: smarty

I'm use Siman CMS and stuck.

{include file="block_begin.tpl"}

How can I change the title name of the block in tpl.

Comment: welcome on stackoverflow! Please expand a bit you question in order to expain better what have you done and what you tried to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use

```
{include file="block_begin.tpl" panel_title="Custom Title"}
```

But there is a `PHP` solution for the block title too.